# Is "I love that for you" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, phrase-usage

Does the phrase "I love that for you" obey the rules of Standard American English, when used in the sense described in [this Vogue article](https://www.vogue.com/article/i-love-that-for-you)?

In particular, the person uttering the sentence is not loving something in place of ("for") someone else; rather, the person is expressing approval of someone else's actions (or disapproval when said sarcastically).

I'm having a hard time parsing it. Compared to "[That's] good for you," "I love that" seems to have a different function than "That's good."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the linked *Vogue* article ("[Why Is Everyone Saying 'I Love That for You?'](https://www.vogue.com/article/i-love-that-for-you)") seems to be a fairly comprehensive history of the phrase's origin, use, and [slide into sarcastic shade](https://reductress.com/post/knock-your-proud-friend-down-a-peg-or-two-by-declaring-i-love-that-for-you/).

Whether sincere or not, of course it's grammatical English in any dialect. Per [the *OED*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/72761), even if you don't think it suits the sense of *for* as

> **VII.** Of the cause or reason. **21.** Because of, on account of: **a.** a person or persons.
>
> ...
>
> **c.** On account of one's regard for.

it still works for

> **IX.** Of reference. **26. a.** As regard, with regard or respect to, concerning...
>
> **b.** So far as concerns (a person or thing). Used with limiting or restrictive force...
>
> ...
>
> **27.** In proportion to, considering; considering the nature or capacity of; considering what he, she, or it is, or that he, etc. is so and so.

That's the sense that's being used in most of the *Vogue* examples: I don't necessarily love this myself (indeed, I probably don't much like it) but it's just perfect for *you* and the kind of person *you* are. And that's a bog standard application of this particular preposition. (The *OED* senses are for the most part ordered the age of the examples, not the amount of present-day usage.)

Comment: I'm sure this doesn't apply to OP themself but with regard to the general tendency in Western culture to think something _must_ be off with new phrases being mostly popularized by young women, the classic text is DWF's ["Tense Present"](https://www.csub.edu/~mault/fosterwallace.htm).

Comment: Are the OED listings VII and XI definitions of *for*?

Comment: Maybe you're right and the novelty of the phrase, not the usage of for, is what's confusing me. I cannot access the OED entry you linked, so please permit me a clarifying question. Are there are common sentences that contain a similar usage? For example, anything of the form "I [verb] that for you?" The closest I can think of is "I'm happy for you," but again it seems somewhat different.

Comment: @alligator Of course. The top ngram results of _I * that for you_ will all sound natural to you. The closest to this is _I want that for you_ and _I get that for you..._ (in senses where _get_ is being used for _understand_). This particular phrase is an innovation but not ungrammatical, although some speakers might very strongly need to hear a decent pause before _for_ in order to parse it correctly.

Comment: Thanks! That may be helpful to add to your answer. I also thought of "I approve of that for you," which helped me bridge the gap between uses that sound idiomatic to me and the phrase in the question.

Comment: “That” always has a referent. In “I bought that for you” that refers to something bought. If you acquire a bright orange hat, I might say “I love that for you” meaning that I’m pleased that you have an orange hat to wear while hunting.  The structure is really conventional.